# "Proper probability distribution must be stongly concave" (as claimed by a book)

Tags: statistics, convex-analysis

I've been going through a reading of Lavenda's *Statistical Physics, A Probabilistic Approach*, and have repeatedly seen the claim that

> [...] in order for $f$ to be a *proper* probability distribution (i.e., a proper fraction), it is necessary that
>
> $$S(\bar X) - S(X) - (\bar X - X)\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial \bar X}\right) > 0$$
>
> which is one definition of a *strictly concave* function.

where the author has previously defined (note the switched expectations)
$$
\ln f(X) = S(X) - S(\bar X) - (X - \bar X)\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial \bar X}\right) 
$$

This claim that a density must be log-concave has also been made to derive several other 'notions' but it's completely unclear where or how this claim emerges---especially since I can think of several distributions which are not log-concave that are "proper" (I also note this idea is never explicitly defined in the text). It's also unclear what "(i.e., a proper fraction)" even *means*.

Perhaps someone might shed some light on this? I may be missing something entirely here. This may also be a question better-posed for Physics.SE, but the claim is supposed to be completely mathematical in nature.

---

Additional details:

The only previous mention of the statement that $f$ must be log-concave in order to be "proper" comes from a few pages before

> In order for the error function to be a proper density, we must have
>   $$\frac{\partial^2 \ln f}{\partial \Delta_i^2} = -\lambda < 0$$
>   for all $i$.

Here the "error function" is perhaps best defined by the following excerpt:

> The differences [between measurement $i$ and the mean],
>   $$\Delta_i = v_i - v,$$
>   are the *errors* committed, and we want to determine the frequency or error curve in which the ordinate gives the number of cases in which the error lies in any given interval $d\Delta_i$. The probability that the error shall lie in this interval is $f(\Delta_i)d\Delta_i$, and the density $f(\Delta_i)$ is the error function we wish to determine.

Comment: I think a little bit more context might be needed to make sense of this. It is indeed true that a density function need not be log-concave, consider for instance the density $x^{-2}$ on $[1,\infty)$ and zero elsewhere. That said, if $S$ is to be understood as *entropy*, then concavity of the entropy is a consequence of the second law of thermodynamics.

Comment: I can try and add some, but really not much more is said in the text. The first mention of this is a few pages before with the claim "In order for the error function to be a proper density, we must have $\partial_{\Delta_i}^2 \ln f < 0$". This is about the only other mention of this before the quoted passage in the question.

Comment: What is "the error function" in this context?

Comment: @Ian Added to the question!

Comment: OK, so it is just the same random variable with the mean subtracted off. Then yes, the only rationale I can see for this is the second law of thermodynamics.

Comment: I only skimmed [the book in question](https://books.google.com/books?id=k-6pDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA32&ots=OVORwhcktB&dq=%22%20for%20the%20error%20function%20to%20be%20a%20proper%20density%22&pg=PA32#v=onepage&q=%22%20for%20the%20error%20function%20to%20be%20a%20proper%20density%22&f=false), but isn't (1.31) using the laws of physics to find what $f$ *has* to be like, and then arguing that for it to actually be the density of a probability distribution (i.e., to begin with, integrable over $\mathbb{R}$), **then** the form of (1.31) enforces log-concavity?

Comment: @ClementC. Kind of, there are indeed some physical arguments (e.g. samples must be independent, and the lagrange multiplier must only depend on the mean quantity), but the second law isn't invoked anywhere. In fact, in (1.31) and after the author claims that we may "relate this to the [...] concavity of entropy since [...] it seems more appropriate." Here it seems (at least how I read it) that the tail is wagging the dog (e.g. concavity suggests the connection that $\ln f$ is some entropy-like thing) , but perhaps I'm reading it wrong.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I read the sentence "We may relate [...]" as an interpretation *after* obtaining the condition that $(\ln f)'' < 0$. This condition was itself obtained directly from (1.31): assuming $f$ is smooth enough one gets $(\ln f)'' = -\lambda$. For $f$ to satisfy $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f <\infty$ (needed to have $f$ being a density), one must have $-\lambda < 0$.

Comment: @ClementC. Ah, yes, you're right (though it's still unclear how this lagrange multiplier was reached in the text, I would only say it makes sense by bounding the variance, not by the weird argument given). But thank you!

Comment: @GuillermoAngeris No problem!

Comment: @GuillermoAngeris Note that the Lagrange multipliers for the usual statistical ensembles all have physical interpretations which lead to assumptions about their sign and what quantities they are permitted to depend on. For example, the Lagrange multiplier for the constant average energy constraint, traditionally denoted as $\beta$, is necessarily a positive number (in thermodynamic equilibrium), since it is proportional to $1/T$ where $T$ is the absolute temperature. Positivity of temperature (in thermodynamic equilibrium) is again a consequence of the second law of thermodynamics.

Comment: @Ian I guess even as a physicist, I sometimes still can't swallow some of these arguments :P but yes, I do agree. Thanks again!